# Access Sub-Contexts of Main-Context in ANTLR4 Tree-Listener

Tags: antlr4

Currently I'm using code like this to access my sub-contexts of a main-context in my tree listener implementation for ANTLR4:

```
ctx.children.forEach(function(child) {
    if (child.ITALIC != undefined) {
        var text = child.ITALIC().getText();

        ...
    } else if (child.LABELREF != undefined) {
        var text = child.LABELREF().getText();

        ...
    }

    ...
```

Due to the fact that I'm using the JavaScript ANTLR4 target I'm not quite sure if this is the correct way of accessing information like this.

If this would be a C# or Java target I think I would find the best way. Or would this result in

```
child.ITALIC != null
```

calls and stuff like that?

The results I get are fine and everything's working. But I'm curious if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is how you could access the individual subparts. Alterntaively, you can just use the `childrens` property of the main context, which contains ParseTree instances (actually either TerminalNode or RuleContext instances, depending on whether it's a terminal or not). This way you don't need to check the individual sub context (which are simply another view of the `childrens` list anyway).

Side note: instead of the sub contexts you can also use variables in your grammar, e.g.

```
expr:
  left = INT op = ('+' | '-') right = INT
  | left = INT op = ('*' | '/') right = INT
;
```

This will create variables `left` and `right` which you can directly access without going to subcontexts.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I saw the childrens property and the different Context or TerminalNode instances in it. But I need to check the type in JavaScript and thought the individual sub context methods are a little bit easier to use?!

Comment: Yes, they are simpler to use and code using the individual access functions is self explaining. However, the children array is the ultimate source of all that and the best point to check if one of the special access functions don't return the expected values.

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. Thanks!